# iOS :Call a method in specific time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to call a method on this time :  `00:01 AM` here is my code but I can't find the problem why this code does not call my method.

```
- (BOOL)date:(NSDate *)date hour:(NSInteger)h minute:(NSInteger)m {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *componets = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit )fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    if ([componets hour ] == h && [componets minute] == m) {

        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}



- (void)updateNewDate {

    if ([self date:[NSDate date] hour:4 minute:49]) {

        label.text = @"oyooy";
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[self updateNewDate];
}
```

If you have any other methods please tell me .

Comment: you sure your application was running at 00:01 AM. i.e the app is running in the foreground ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your code works fine but it needs refreshing ... for example you can use `NSTimer`
to refresh your method :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(updateNewDate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Local Notification is the way to go....

EDIT...
 Second way is to get the current time whenever the app launches and find the time till next midnight , then start a timer to fire after that time interval.
hope this helps.

Comment: No I don't want use local notif

Comment: Can this be done in background? without bringing the app to foreground?