# Run function at specific time on iOS?

Tags: ios, notifications, recurring-events

I want my iPhone application to run a function at a time that the user sets and can change.

The function fetches an xml file, parses it, and sends a notification to the user if necessary.

How do I schedule the function to run at a specific time/day? I know that on Android there is the BroadcastReceiver and AlarmManager. Are there any similar functions on iOS?

Edit: The function would still need to run even if the application is closed.

Comment: this may helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211640/ios-call-a-method-in-specific-time

Comment: Hmm. In applications that I've made in the past I've always used NSTimer for loops while the application is running. Will an NSTimer persist even after the phone is rebooted?

Comment: I think what you are after is `UILocalNotification`

Comment: Is there a way to run a function along with the notification to determine whether the notification needs to be sent?

Comment: No, that would be impossible.  You can cancel it if your app is running but otherwise the system controls it.

Comment: Is it possible to run a function after the notification has already been sent?

Answer (score 0):

Read the file/userdefualts etc for the specified time.

Start a timer.

If the time matches or passed, hit the method.

Comment: This point hit me first. :p And I am sure you would have half a dozen more way to do this;

Comment: After the application is terminated will the timer persist? That's the key feature.

Comment: It will start again as with your application? do you want to call the method even when app is closed!!

Comment: Yeah, like a BroadcastReceiver. Is this not possible on iOS? How do developers create dynamic recurring notifications?